# These shouldn't have been downvoted

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Software Center will not start from icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784699/software-center-will-not-start-from-icon) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/784695/ubuntu-store-wont-launch shouldn't have been downvoted. It this more of the malicious up-down voting?

Comment: The second question isn't particularly clear to be honest. Disclaimer: I didn't downvote either of them.

Comment: The second question is off-topic because it is about a development issue. The other question seems on-topic enough, but people have different criterion.  As long as you vote on the post and not the person, no one is stopping you from using your up/down votes as you like.

Comment: The first one likely got downvoted because, looking at the revision history, it was a mess, a big block of output with no formating or anything. It looks good now but when it was first posted, it did not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for the first link I can explain you why it got a down-vote, you will get the clue to when you look at this posts [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/784699/revisions). At the time I edited it first it was already down-voted, and my guess is because the question was a mess to read, totally without formatting.

Still a legit question, but some people react on first impression and move on leaving only the down-vote because they are disgusted by the format a question is represented. My standpoint is instead of down-voting, we should encourage people to do an edit to improve this question. But maybe I'm still seeing good things where others only see bad.

To your second question I cant say much beside that is not really clear to me what is being asked.

To come back to your own question, no that is not malicious up/down-voting continuing, it is just the day to day craziness we see sadly often enough.

Comment: I have been on here long enough to see that same craziness. :(